# GLSL "in" structs

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm not allowed to use a struct with the `in` keyword, am I? For example:

```
struct Rect {
    float x,y,width,height;
};

layout(location = 7) in Rect TexSrc;
```

It's difficult to Google, but I get an error when I try to use my GLSL shader (`INVALID_OPERATION`). It appears I'm allowed to use `float[4]` however.

If I'm not allowed to use a struct, what do you suggest I do? Construct the struct out of a `float[4]`, or suck it up, forgo the nice API, and use indices 0-3 everywhere?

(A `vec4` would work here as well, I know, but `z` and `w` don't have quite the same meaning as "width" and "height", and this is only one example)

I suppose you can only specify a single type per location with `glVertexAttribPointer`, so I can see why a struct would be disallowed... I'm just trying to think of a way to keep my code clean and ledgible without compromising performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have vertex shader inputs of `struct`s.

The correct way to do this is to just stick them in a `vec4`. If you use a `float[4]`, this will require *four attributes* instead of just one. Arrays always take up one attribute per element. So if you do `layout(location = 7) in float[4] TexSrc;`, this will take up the attribute indices 7, 8, 9, and 10. That's an awful waste of attributes, and it could degrade performance.

Just use a `vec4` like everyone else. People pack inputs in `vec4`s all the time; they use comments to explain any semantic oddities.

BTW, if you're getting an invalid operation, that probably means you didn't actually check to see if your shader compiled and linked properly. You should [always do that](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL#Error_Checking).

#### New stuff

OpenGL 4.4 or the ARB_enhanced_layouts extension, allow you to do something *like* this.

As previously stated, the main problem with `layout(location = 7) in float[4] TexSrc;` is that it takes up 4 input locations. So if you have 4 floats that aren't really a 4D vector, you still have to pack them into a `vec4` for shipping into the shader:

```
layout(location = 7) in vec4 rect;
```

This makes it a lot harder to know what `rect.z` means in the shader, since it doesn't have any explicit meaning.

4.4/enhanced_layouts allow you to [pack multiple variables in a single location, so long as their components don't overlap](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_%28GLSL%29#Interface_components). So if each location is conceptually a `vec4`, we can split that into 2 `vec2`s:

```
layout(location = 7, component = 0) in vec2 rectPos;
layout(location = 7, component = 2) in vec2 rectSize;
```

Now we get some semantic information. `rectPos` is the position of the rectangle, while `rectSize` is its size. And it still only takes up one location.

The enhanced layouts feature allows this to work for *any* inputs and outputs, not just vertex shaders.

Comment: OpenTK is supposed to throw exceptions if there's a GL error automatically. Never seems to happen on `glLinkProgram`, but it does happen elsewhere (such as on `glUseProgram`). I'll use a `vec4` then. Just wanted to affirm I was on the right track, thanks!

Comment: Throw exceptions on any GL error?  You know how inefficient it is to flush the pipeline and check for error after every single command?

Comment: @Mark: Failing to link is not the same as a GL error. You need to actually *check* for a failed compile/link.

Comment: @BenVoigt: They're within `#if DEBUG` blocks; they won't even be compiled into Release.

Comment: @NicolBolas: You mean via `glGetError`? Because that's what I meant. The framework calls `glGetError` after every `gl*` function and throws the result as an exception. `glLinkProgram` doesn't have a return value, so there's nothing else for me to check, is there? Actually, I just found this `glGetProgramInfoLog`...do I need to call that after linking?

Comment: @Mark: Follow the link I gave you. That's why I put the link in "always do that" in my answer. It explains in excruciating detail with a code example (in C mind you) of how to do it.

Comment: Ah.. `glGetShaderiv` w/ `GL_COMPILE_STATUS` and *then* `glGetShaderInfoLog` for more info. Sorry, should have checked the link. Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly in the OpenGL/GLSL specifications does it say that structs are not valid vertex shader input types? Don't get me wrong, I believe you, and it makes complete sense, but I would also like to document by code with exact reference to the specifications.

Comment: @bofjas: You could just look at the GLSL specification. It is, unsurprisingly, in the section titled ["Input Variables"](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#input-variables)